# VIM "upgraded" to expandtab and tabstop=8 on Python files

Tags: ubuntu, vim, python, kubuntu

After reinstalling my OS from Kubuntu 12.10 to Kubuntu 14.04, VIM has changed its behaviour when editing Python files. Though before the reinstall all file types had `noexpandtab` and `tabstop=4` set, now in Python those values are `expandtab` and `tabstop=8`, checked also via VIM behaviour and also via asking VIM `set foo?`.

Non-Python files retain the `noexpandtab` and `tabstop=4` behaviour that I prefer.

The `.vim` direcotry and `.vimrc` were not touched during the reinstall. It can be seen that no files in `.vimrc` have been touched in months (with the exception of the irrelevant `.netrwhist`):

```
 - bruno():~$ ls -lat ~/.vim
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 85 dotancohen dotancohen 12288 Aug 25 13:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 12 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Aug 21 11:11 .
-rw-r--r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   268 Aug 21 11:11 .netrwhist
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Mar  6 18:31 plugin
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Mar  6 18:31 doc
drwxrwxr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Nov 29  2013 syntax
drwxrwxr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Nov 29  2013 ftplugin
drwxr-xr-x  4 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Nov 29  2013 autoload
drwxrwxr-x  5 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 May 27  2013 after
drwxr-xr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Nov  1  2012 spell
-rw-------  1 dotancohen dotancohen   138 Aug 14  2012 .directory
-rw-rw-r--  1 dotancohen dotancohen   190 Jul  3  2012 .VimballRecord
drwxrwxr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 May 12  2012 colors
drwxrwxr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Mar 16  2012 mytags
drwxrwxr-x  2 dotancohen dotancohen  4096 Feb 14  2012 keymap
```

Though `.vimrc` has been touched since the reinstall, it was only me testing to see where the problem is.

**How can I tell what is `settingexpandtab` and `tabstop`?**

Side note: I'm not even sure what I should read in the built-in help for this issue. I started with ":h plugin" but that did not help other than showing me that the following plugins are loaded (possibly relevant):

```
                                                standard-plugin-list    
Standard plugins
pi_getscript.txt Downloading latest version of Vim scripts
pi_gzip.txt      Reading and writing compressed files
pi_netrw.txt     Reading and writing files over a network
pi_paren.txt     Highlight matching parens
pi_tar.txt       Tar file explorer
pi_vimball.txt   Create a self-installing Vim script
pi_zip.txt       Zip archive explorer

LOCAL ADDITIONS:                                local-additions
DynamicSigns.txt - Using Signs for different things
NrrwRgn.txt   A Narrow Region Plugin (similar to Emacs)
fugitive.txt  A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal
indent-object.txt         Text objects based on indent levels.
taglist.txt     Plugin for browsing source code
vimwiki.txt   A Personal Wiki for Vim
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check where those values were changed via

```
:verbose setlocal ts? et?
```

Likely, it's by this added line in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`:

> ```
> " As suggested by PEP8.
> setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
> ```

You can undo this via a script `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with the following contents

```
setlocal noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=0 tabstop=4
```

Or, if you want to configure tabs per project, not globally, add

```
let g:python_recommended_style=0
```

to project's `.vimrc`. After that python plugin will not enforce PEP8 recommendations and you free to setup tabs in proect's `.vimrc`.